# I cannot perform some input in C

Tags: c, input

I'm very new at computer program, C is my first programming language. I learn the code from book and now I'm at the input lesson. I try to write this code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
char name[99], web_address[99], address[99];
    int age;

    printf("Insert your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);

    printf("Your web address: ");
    fgets(web_address, sizeof(web_address), stdin);

    printf("Insert your age: ");
    scanf("%i", &age);

    printf("Insert your address for more information: ");
    fgets(address, sizeof(address), stdin);


    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("my name is %s", name);
    printf("My web address are %s", web_address);
    printf("my age is  %i\n", age);
    printf("and my home address are %s", address);

    return 0;
}
```

There is no error or warning at build log, but when I try to run this code I can't input my address in it.

Comment: Mixing `fgets` and `scanf` doesn't work very well because of the way `scanf` handles whitespace. Try reading the `age` as a string using `fgets`, and then convert the `age` to a number with `sscanf`.

Comment: @dfdhfshdkjfh Do you want to keep the `'\n'` in `name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was create an `ageChar[10]` array that would store the age. Then convert it to an integer using `sscanf` and stored it inside of the `age` variable (Suggested by user3386109).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name[99], web_address[99], address[99], ageChar[10];
    int age;

    printf("Insert your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);

    printf("Your web address: ");
    fgets(web_address, sizeof(web_address), stdin);

    printf("Insert your age: ");
    fgets(ageChar, sizeof(age), stdin);
    sscanf(ageChar, "%d", &age);

    printf("Insert your address for more information: ");
    fgets(address, sizeof(address), stdin);


    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("my name is %s", name);
    printf("My web address are %s", web_address);
    printf("my age is  %d\n", age);
    printf("and my home address are %s\n", address);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the buffer, do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
char name[99], web_address[99], address[99];
    int age;
    char ch; //CREATE NEW VARIABLE

    printf("Insert your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);

    printf("Your web address: ");
    fgets(web_address, sizeof(web_address), stdin);

    printf("Insert your age: ");
    scanf("%i", &age);
    while ((getchar()) != '\n');
    ch = getchar(); //CLEAN THE BUFFER

    printf("Insert your address for more information: ");
    fgets(address, sizeof(address), stdin);


    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("my name is %s", name);
    printf("My web address are %s", web_address);
    printf("my age is  %i\n", age);
    printf("and my home address are %s", address);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The behavior of `fflush` on `stdin` is undefined.

Comment: `ch = getchar();` reads and does not use the first character meant for `address`.

Comment: I tried both, with and without the while LOOP, and both worked